# Querying many-to-many relationship in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

lets say we have this table a_b, which is a many-to-many-relationship with table a and b:

```
+------+------+
| a_id | b_id |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
+------+------+
```

Now i want to query this table, so that i get all a_ids, which have a entry for b_id (1, 2, 3). In the above example, the output should be

```
+------+
| a_id |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
```

cause `a_id = 2` has no entry for `b_id = 3`

one possible query would be:

```
select *
from a
join a_b as a_b1 
    on a_b1.a_id = a.id and a_b1.b_id = 1
join a_b as a_b2 
    on a_b2.a_id = a.id and a_b2.b_id = 2
join a_b as a_b3 
    on a_b3.a_id = a.id and a_b3.b_id = 3
```

but... naaaa...
what would be a bether solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simpler method is `group by` and `having`:

```
select a_id
from a_b
where b_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by a_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

Comment: I'd do `having count(distinct b_id) = 3`, in case of duplicates.